# Excel in Perl - Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

```
use strict;
use lib qw(./lib);
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Math::Random qw(:all);


    $worksheet->write(0, 0, "Zahl", $format); 
    $worksheet->write(0, 1, "Vorkommt",$bold);

    my @rand_arr = map int,random_normal(10,5,5);

    my ($temp,$count) = ("@rand_arr", 0);   
    ($count = $temp =~ s/($_)//g) and printf "%2d:%s vor.\n", $_,$count for @rand_arr;

    $worksheet->write(1, 0, "$_");
    $worksheet->write(1, 1, "$count");


    $workbook->close();

    print "\n";
```

if u do that u gonna get a good output in the Terminal, but what iam trying to do is, to get the same output in the Excel and i think my problem is here

```
$worksheet->write(1, 0, "$_");
$worksheet->write(1, 1, "$count");
```

i dont know how to let excel go alone with the $ROW++..

Comment: my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("try.xls");
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

Comment: thx for the Nice Style note... do u have any idea how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your output to terminal code is doing - it looks very odd.

Perhaps you just want:

```
for my $row (0..$#rand_arr) {
    $worksheet->write($row+1, 0, $row);
    $worksheet->write($row+1, 1, $rand_arr[$row]);
}
```

Comment: thats what i was searching for thanks a lot... but i still got one problem. $worksheet->write($row+1, 0, $row); its giving me 1-10 and not what he count befor why ?

Comment: look the output from Terminal example :
6:2
3:2 
8:2 
2:1  
4:2 
0:1 -> number 6 came 2 times, number 3 came twice...

Comment: I can't tell what your code that generates the Terminal output is supposed to be doing, but looking at it, I suspect it doesn't do what you actually want.  If you edit your question to describe in English what it is supposed to do, with sample random_normal() input and terminal output, I will change my answer to do that.